# Fault Exception windows phone connecting to WCF WP8

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have created a WCF which I then created a WP8 application and added the service reference. The error is "An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code"

If anyone could possible give me some indication as I have googled this and found nothing the same.

The error comes up here

```
public void EndAddUser(System.IAsyncResult result) 
{
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    base.EndInvoke("AddUser", _args, result);
}
```

My main classes:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Service1Client _serviceClient;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _serviceClient = new Service1Client();
        _serviceClient.LoginUserCompleted += new     

    }

    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _serviceClient.LoginUserAsync(userNameTxtBox.Text, passwordTxtBox.Text);

    }

    private void newAccountBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AddAccount.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void _serviceClient_LoginUserCompleted(object senter,         
    LoginUserCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + e.Result + "!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not log in. Please check user name/password and try
          again.");                  
        }
    }
}



public partial class AddAccount : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private Service1Client _serviceClient;

    public AddAccount()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _serviceClient = new Service1Client();
        _serviceClient.AddUserCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>
        (_serviceClient_AddUserCompleted);
    }

    private void addAccountBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _serviceClient.AddUserAsync(fullnameTxtBox.Text, userNameTxtBox.Text,   
       passwordTxtBox.Text);
    }

    void _serviceClient_AddUserCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User account created. Please login");
            this.NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User account could not be added, Please try again");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Catch the exception 2. call `.ToString()` on the exception 3. copy the entire text of the result of the call and 4. [edit] your question and add this information here.  It probably contains all that is needed to figure out the problem.

Comment: Check that you have the right url and the service is working.
To make this tests you can use WCFTestClient.exe found in the same folder where VisualStudio is (devenv.exe)